# Запросы в БД MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

В базу записанный IP, необходимо вызывать нужный IP в нужном месте, но вот не могу сообразить как. Один IP знаю как вызвать

```
public String Getdata()
        {
            dt = new DataTable("print");
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mySqlCSB;
            mySqlCSB = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            mySqlCSB.Server = "localhost";
            mySqlCSB.Database = "ip";
            mySqlCSB.UserID = "root";
            mySqlCSB.Password = "813410";

            string query = @"SELECT `ip` FROM `print` WHERE cab = 10";

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = mySqlCSB.ConnectionString;

                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                sb.Append(dr.GetString("ip"));

                            }
                            dt.Load(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

а здесь я его выгружаю из базы.

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Getdata());
```

Проблема в том что у меня много таких запросов с IP и возник вопрос как можно `Getdata` вызывать для каждого `IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Getdata());` и получить нужный IP который должен там быть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что у вас каждый раз разная переменная `cab`, исходя из этого внесу правки в ваш код.

```
public String Getdata(int cab)
{
    ...
    var query = string.Format(@"SELECT `ip` FROM `print` WHERE cab = {0}", cab);
    ...
}
```

ну и собственно ваш вызов:

```
var ipAddr = Getdata(10);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddr))
{
   var address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr);
   // действия с переменной address
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за поправки, но столкнулся с ошибкой  Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "ipString" из "IPAddress.Parse(string)"

Comment: @Павел, спасибо за наблюдательность, сейчас поправлю код

Comment: ещё не хватает скобки (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddr))

Comment: @Павел действительно :) не проснулся еще

Comment: столкнулся с проблемой, когда я сделал var ipAddr = Getdata(10); всё нормально но когда я ниже добавил var ipAddr = Getdata(805); то выдало ошибку что var ipAddr = Getdata(10);Указан недопустимый адрес IP. в базе всё нормально

Comment: @Павел, мало информации, нужно больше, я пока не могу понять где у вас ошибка. напишите что у вас в базе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32199/discussion-between--and-dmitry).